# Efficient way to load lots of images in python

Tags: python, performance, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

[image: Loading images from folder]

Here I am trying to load train images in Google Colab. Here 100000 images are available in 10 subfolders. This cell is running for 54 Minute. It takes more time than that. Is there any efficient way to do that?

Comment: why are you loading this much data in memory?

Comment: For training deep-learning model

Comment: Please use data generators instead of loading all the data at once

Answer (score 1):

One of the efficient and prodominant way is using data loaders of machine learning frameworks, such as tensorflow, pytorch. Acoording to your code, you're loading all images at the time and this takes much time. If there were many images, then you will probably get `MemoryError`. I highly recommend you to use `DataLoader` in PyTorch, Tensorflow. DataLoaders loads the ***batch of data*** during the training process.

In Tensorflow [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image_dataset_from_directory), you can use following structure:

```
tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory, labels='inferred', label_mode='int',
    class_names=None, color_mode='rgb', batch_size=32, image_size=(256,
    256), shuffle=True, seed=None, validation_split=None, subset=None,
    interpolation='bilinear', follow_links=False
)
```

In PyTorch [doc](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/datasets.html?highlight=imagefolder#torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder), but here firstly you need to specify the dataset then, you will give it to data loader:

```
imagenet_data = torchvision.datasets.ImageNet('path/to/imagenet_root/')
data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(imagenet_data,
                                          batch_size=4,
                                          shuffle=True,
                                          num_workers=args.nThreads)
```

Above mentioned data loading approaches are widely used because of efficiency. I hope using of them helps you to tackle with the task.